# UbuntuからWindowsのホスト名を解決したい

Tags: linux, windows, network

UbuntuからWindowsマシンのホスト名を、NetBIOSによって名前解決をしたいです。

やったことは、

- `sudo apt purge avahi-daemon`
- `sudo apt install winbind libnss-winbind`
- `/etc/nsswitch.conf` の `hosts:` の行の最後に `wins` を追加

この設定で、Ubuntu 16.04ではできていましたが、Ubuntu 18.04でできなくなりました。

今私のネットワークには次のマシンがあるとします。

- 10.10.10.205/24 alice (Ubuntu18)
- 10.10.10.200/24 julia (Windows10)

aliceからjuliaにpingを実行します。

```
soramimi@alice:~$ ping julia
ping: julia: 名前またはサービスが不明です
```

同じことを、Ubuntu16やWindows10のコマンドプロンプトで実行すると、pingの結果が帰ってきます。Ubuntu18では、上記の通り「名前またはサービスが不明です」というエラーになります。

このときの通信パケットは次のようなものでした。

[image: wireshark]
NetBIOS Name Service のリクエストとレスポンスは成功しているようです。リクエストのブロードキャストに対して、10.10.10.200が応答していることがわかります。このIPアドレスに対するpingは正常ですし、Remmina（リモートデスクトップ）による接続もできたので、問い合わせに対する結果は正しいことがわかります。ですが、Ubuntu18のリゾルバがそのIPアドレスを返してくれないようです。

この原因と解決策として考えられることは何でしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事があるようですが。[Ubuntu 18.04 にしたら NetBios name で Windows マシンにアクセスできなくなった【解決】](https://kokufu.blogspot.com/2018/09/ubuntu-1804-netbios-name-windows.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。Ubuntu18からはavahiがデフォルトになったと書いてありますね、でも、 `.local` などを付けたくないのでmDNSではなくNetBIOS/WINSでやりたいと思っています。そして、16ではできていたことが18でできなくなった原因を知りたいです。

Comment: 色々あるようです。どれかが参考になれば。[SambaV1がWin10から削除関連](https://askubuntu.com/q/1038760), [色んな回答記事あり](https://askubuntu.com/q/1068131), [winbindとsambaの関係?](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1789097), [関連してるか不明だが4つの方法](https://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-dns-problems-after-upgrading-ubuntu-17-10-from-ubuntu-17-04-16-10-16-04.html), [長いスレッド](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400112), [何かが解決](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2406092)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04からUbuntu 18.04へアップグレードという事なので、もしかしたら systemd 関連かもと思い、検索してみた所、[\[SOLVED\] winbind does not work after reboot on Mint 19 / Ubuntu 18.04](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=276346)が引っ掛かりました。ご参考までにどうぞ。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解答です。

結論から言うと、nsswitch用の名前解決ライブラリを自作しました。

コメントで頂いた 「[[SOLVED] winbind does not work after reboot on Mint 19 / Ubuntu 18.04](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=276346)」 ならびに、同内容の 「[winbind does not work after reboot on Mint 19 / Ubuntu 18.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1789097)」 そして、それを参照している日本語の記事「[Ubuntu18.04/Mint19でwinbindが再起動後に起動しない](https://qiita.com/Urushibara01/items/3b55646e228d82c34e48)」といった情報が見つかりました。

これらによると、systemdがサービスを起動する順番の定義に問題があるらしく、解決策としては、Sambaをインストールするか`/lib/systemd/system/winbind.service`を修正するとのことでした。しかし私の環境では、いずれの方法も解決に至りませんでした。やり方が間違っている可能性はあるものの、それ以上追求するのは諦めました。

その後、ソケットを使ったUDP通信で NetBIOS Naming Service のプロトコルで、[ホスト名を問い合わせるプログラム](https://qiita.com/soramimi_jp/items/041eae2465f3ec985b99)を作りました。

また、GitHubでnsswitchの名前解決ライブラリを作る方法を探して、[自前の名前解決ライブラリ](https://qiita.com/soramimi_jp/items/9282a83664355c563c37)を作ることができました。

この二つを組み合わせて`libnss-winbind`の代替品を作りました。

https://github.com/soramimi/libnss-winz

`make`して、`sudo make install`して、`/etc/nsswitch.conf`内の`hosts:`の定義の最後に`winz`と書くと使えるようになります。

Answer (score 1):

`winbindd`(8) は動作していますか? (動いているようだけど念の為)

`wbinfo --WINS-by-name julia` で `winbindd` に `julia` の名前解決を依頼したとき、どのような応答が得られますか?

IP アドレス `10.10.10.200` のホストがブロードキャスト宛の名前解決要求に応答していますが、応答によると `JULIA<20>` の IP アドレスは `192.168.222.1` と答えているように見えます。この IP アドレスに心当たりはありませんか?

mDNS でも `resolv.conf`(5) で `search local` とでも書いておけば `.local` 付けずに済むと思うのですが、それでは駄目なのでしょうか?